# VB.Net windows form graphics running slowly on Windows 10

Tags: vb.net

Using VB2010 on an old Windows 7 computer I have written some Win Form code to graphically simulate static and it runs quickly.

When this same code is run on a newer Windows 10 machine using VB2010 is runs very slowly (about a tenth of the speed). It also runs slowly on my Windows 10 laptop using VB2010. I have also tried it on both my Windows 10 machines using VS2017 and it is still slow.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Math

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Show()
        DoStatic()

    End Sub

    Private Sub DoStatic()

        Dim lineGreen As New Pen(Color.LightGreen)
        Dim lineBlack As New Pen(Color.Black)
        Dim formGraphics As Graphics

        Dim staticAmplitudeUpper As Integer
        Dim staticAmplitudeLower As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer

        formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()

        y = 200

        For duration As Integer = 1 To 10

            For x = 20 To 1020

                staticAmplitudeUpper = CInt(Ceiling(Rnd() * 5)) + 1
                staticAmplitudeLower = CInt(Ceiling(Rnd() * 5)) + 1

                formGraphics.DrawLine(lineBlack, x, y - 6, x, y + 6)
                formGraphics.DrawLine(lineGreen, x, y, x, 200 - staticAmplitudeUpper)
                formGraphics.DrawLine(lineGreen, x, y, x, 200 + staticAmplitudeLower)

            Next

        Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: That's wrong from the outset.  Despite the number of examples that do it for simplicity, you should NEVER call `CreateGraphics`.  You need to move your drawing code to the `Paint` event handler or `OnPaint` method and use the `Graphics` object provided.

Comment: Also, there's no need to create `Pen` objects for standard `Color` values.  The `Pens` class already provides them.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your code is supposed to be doing because you've decided that providing no comments is a good strategy.  It's not.  Is that code supposed to be  changing what is seen on screen as it executes or what?  Have you actually done any timing to see where the time is actually being taken?

Comment: This is a CPU hog. Your code will utilize as much CPU as it can and its speed is therefore also determined (more than usual) by how much CPU power it can get. Like jmcilhinney said this should be moved to the `Paint` event, and instead of the `For duration` loop use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` that calls `Me.Invalidate()` to cause the `Paint` event to be raised again and thus update the animation.